# PHP script with PostgreSQL commands returning NULL for JSon data

Tags: php, json, web-services, postgresql

I created a very simple PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"()
 RETURNS SETOF betya_ref."tbl_BET_TYPES" AS
$BODY$
SELECT * FROM betya_ref."tbl_BET_TYPES";    
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 20;
ALTER FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() TO public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() TO dummy_users;
```

I tested the function within pgAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"()
```

And it returned correct results:

```
ID  NAME     
1   WIN/LOSE
2   TRUE/FALSE"
3   TRUE/ALTERN TRUE"
4   RIGHT/WRONG"
```

I created a PHP script, sitting in an Apache 2.2 server under the directory "Apache2.2\htdocs\server\betya_ref\getBetTypes.php":

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=192.168.1.222 port=5432 dbname=betya user=dummy_user password=dummy_pass")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
print('connect ... ' . $dbconn); //debugging
 $result=pg_query($dbconn, 'SELECT * FROM betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"()');
 print(' ***  result ... ' . $result); //debugging  
 while($e=pg_fetch_row($result))
$output[]=$e;
print('  *** output ... ' . $output . '... *** JSon ...'); //debugging
print(json_encode($output));

pg_free_result($result);

pg_close($dbconn);
```

I call the PHP script in a browser using this URL:

```
http://localhost/server/betya_ref/getBetTypes.php
```

Which returns:

```
connect ... Resource id #2 *** result ... *** output ... ... *** JSon ...null
```

Other (very similar) existing scripts I run return and display the JSon data correctly with the same connection string and from the same directory, but from a different schema within the same database. This new schema has the following permissions;

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA betya_ref TO postgres;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA betya_ref TO betya_users;
```

I'm thinking there is an error in the PHP script, but can't see where I am wrong, considering everything is so simple, and straight from the PHP manual.  What haven't I considered?

Comment: Server is running with PHP and Postgress enabled and tested.

Comment: Also I've tried straight SQL instead of a function call in the PHP with the same result.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($output)` after the 2nd last print statement?

Comment: What do you get back when you run SELECT * FROM betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() in pgadmin or otherwise directly against the database without PHP?

Comment: It appears although permissions are set on the function, permission aren't set on the "betya_ref.tbl_BET_TYPES" table itself, but is required.

    GRANT ALL ON TABLE betya_ref."tbl_BET_TYPES" TO admin;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE betya_ref."tbl_BET_TYPES" TO dummy_users;

Comment: I dont have enough rep to post an answer yet but the above comment gives the solution for me.

Comment: Try showing pg_last_error() after the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION betya_ref."func_GetBetTypes"() TO public;
```

would cover it. Except that you don't even need that. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)

> For other types of objects, the default privileges granted to `PUBLIC` are as follows: [...] `EXECUTE` privilege for functions and procedures;

No need to `GRANT` any more privileges *on the function*. The `GRANT` to `postgres` is just noise, too, because `postgres` is a superuser who ignores privileges.

You also:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA betya_ref TO betya_users;
```

Is `betya_users` supposed to be the same as `dummy_users`?
And did you `GRANT dummy_users TO dummy_user` (singular)?

Did you also:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE betya_ref."tbl_BET_TYPES" TO `dummy_user`
```

directly or indirectly? Privileges for a function do *not* cover privileges on the involved tables, unless you make the function `SECURITY DEFINER`. In this case, be sure to read the chapter [**"Writing `SECURITY DEFINER` Functions Safely"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) in the manual.

I don't see an error message, though. With missing privileges there should be an error message.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with permmissions on the table itself.  Thankyou.  I didn't see any error messages however, especially regarding permissions.  I happened to stumble upon this solution by chance after posting this question.