# How to grant EXECUTE permissions for yet to be defined functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, permissions, privileges

I'm running a SQL script that creates an user first then defines some functions. How can I grant permissions to `EXECUTE` the yet to be defined functions without giving the grant after defining the functions? And also functions that I define in the future?

I've tried unsuccessfully altering the default privileges like this:

```
alter default privileges for user admin in schema myschema
GRANT execute ON functions TO admin;
```

Giving the grant after running the script like this works, but I'd like to not have to run it each time I define new functions:

```
grant execute on all functions in schema myschema to admin;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't have to do anything.** Just keep reading.

Once you have executed [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), manual `GRANT` like you suggest is not needed any more. The defined privilege(s) are granted automatically, like you desire - for the defined creating role, the defined receiving role, in the defined schema.

You do have `admin` twice in your statement, which does not make sense, as the creator is the initial owner of the function and, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html):

> Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner

And yo may want to use `ROUTINE` instead of `FUNCTION` in modern Postgres (version 11 or later). [The manual on `GRANT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

> The `FUNCTION` syntax works for plain functions, aggregate functions,
> and window functions, but not for procedures; use `PROCEDURE` for
> those. Alternatively, use `ROUTINE` to refer to a function, aggregate
> function, window function, or procedure regardless of its precise
> type.

However (somewhat confusingly) the manual on `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` has this to say:

> For this command, functions include aggregates and procedures. The
> words `FUNCTIONS` and `ROUTINES` are equivalent in this command.
> (`ROUTINES` is preferred going forward as the standard term for
> functions and procedures taken together. In earlier PostgreSQL
> releases, only the word `FUNCTIONS` was allowed. It is not possible to
> set default privileges for functions and procedures separately.)

Either way, `ROUTINES` would typically be the right choice in modern Postgres. Run this after creating `creating_role`:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE creating_role IN SCHEMA myschema
GRANT EXECUTE ON ROUTINES TO receiving_role;
```

Then, `receiving_role` has the right to *execute* those functions. **Except** that in a standard setup, `PUBLIC` has the right to execute anyway. And every role is automatically member of `PUBLIC`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)

> For other types of objects, the default privileges granted to `PUBLIC` are as follows: [...] `EXECUTE` privilege for functions and procedures;

So you don't have to do anything.

Are you aware that the bare privilege to `EXECUTE` does not give any privileges beyond that? In particular, tables etc. are accessed with the privileges of the executing role. You may be looking for [`SECURITY DEFINER` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY). Related:

- [PHP script with PostgreSQL commands returning NULL for JSon data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899247/php-script-with-postgresql-commands-returning-null-for-json-data/9899506#9899506)